# Can Informix 4gl be run on Azure Could?

Tags: cloud, informix, 4gl

We are planning to migrate Informix DB to Azure cloud, but we have a lot of 4gl programs running on server. Is Azure cloud support 4gl? and any reference can be shared. Many thanks.

Comment: Where are you planning to run the 4GL programs? On Azure or on your 'local' machines. If is the later I see no problems as 4GL supports TLS connections which is what you should use to get traffic into your server.

Comment: I have to run the 4GL on Azure, because our company is going to give up the on premise server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to install 4GL on whatever VM you used on Azure (I am unaware of any third party marketplace offerings which come with 4GL preinstalled) - but you should have no issues running your applications once you install the 4GL stack.

We have run 4GL applications using Genero - a 4GL compatible product which provides supports numerous graphical clients - and IBM Informix, both 11.70- and 12.10 - for over three years, and had no issues.

Comment: I can find the HCL Informix in marketplace, but cannot find the material to prove it can support 4GL.

Comment: Hi Henry - the HCL informix will give you an informix server on a VM. I don't believe it will include 4GL, but it may - you'd need to check directly with HCL.  However, as I indicated, you should have no problem installing your own licensed 4GL on the VM, and then running your applications.  You can also run your 4GL application on a Four Js Genero runtime, which I am certain works on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it helps but we are running fine Informix 4GL (and Informix) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux servers. I'm pretty confident, Genero would work too on distribution like debian or RHEL

Comment: Re: Genero, correct.  See supported documentation https://4js.com//mirror/documentation.php?s=genero&f=fjs-genero-3.20.XX-PlatformsDb.pdf